Decode human-readable Error in pallet
I am using ethers.js to estimate the gas for a transaction on a Substrate-based chain with EVM compatibility. However, I received the following error: Module(ModuleError { index: 55, error: [4, 0, 0, 0], message: None }). How can I decode the correct pallet name, error name, and message?

55 is the pallet index.
For example, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/2f3a1bf8736844272a7eb165780d9f283b19d5c0/templates/minimal/runtime/src/lib.rs#L101.
And [4,0,0,0] is the encoded error enum. It is the fifth one of the Error, since count starts from 0.
For example, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/2f3a1bf8736844272a7eb165780d9f283b19d5c0/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L389.
But if you can use polkadot-js, it will fetch the metadata and decode the error for you.

Can I use the SDK to decode it?
Input: Module(ModuleError { index: 55, error: [4, 0, 0, 0], message: None })  + Metadata of the network -> Output : Human-readable String

What SDK? polkadot.js?

I believe PAPI is one of the TypeScript SDKs designed to handle errors. I'm currently working with the PolkadotJS API, but its usage is not very clear.
